# How can one calculate brightness of a flame?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, combustion

I imagine there must be many factors involved in order to do so, but what are they, and what mathematical formulas are useable?

Perhaps a candle, for example is a better concrete circumstance, but I'm curious about what kind of mathematical abstractions exist about fire.

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking. Your question is too abstract. Also, no research effort!

Comment: I think you want the result in candela? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you may use the equation for black body radiation to calculate the temperature of the flame based on the color

[image].

Comment: While the glowing of soot may be close to a black body, there are other complexities going on in a flame, such as discrete energy transitions, that are not described by a black body.